# How can I shorten conditional formatting expressions with multiple cases

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have written a macro which colors the values in a lab report for pollutants based on limit values specified in another worksheet. However, since there are 27 different pollutants, each with five different limit values (pollution classes), I had to write 27 (quite long) expressions to apply formatting for each individual case. Thus, the entire macro becomes unmanageably long.

The lab report is in a transposed table format, with the cases in rows rather than in columns, and the first case starts on row 7.
The structure of the macro is as follows:

1. identify the row heading for the specific case, e.g. Arsenic

   ```
   Set rngHeaderAs = Range("A7").CurrentRegion.Find("As*Arsen*", LookAt:=xlPart)
   Set rngAs = Range(rngHeaderAs, rngHeaderAs.End(xlToRight))
   AsAddress = rngAs.Address(False, False)
   ```
2. Define the limit values for the case:

   ```
   Dim Ul1As As Double
   Ul1As = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(2, "B").Value
   Dim Ul2As As Double
   Ul2As = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(2, "C").Value
   Dim Ul3As As Double
   Ul3As = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(2, "D").Value
   Dim Ul4As As Double
   Ul4As = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(2, "E").Value
   Dim Ul5As As Double
   Ul5As = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(2, "F").Value
   ```
3. Apply conditional formatting for all five classes:

   With ActiveSheet

   ```
   With rngAs
       .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & AsAddress & ");" & AsAddress & "<" & Ul1As & ")"
       .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
       .FormatConditions(1).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .FormatConditions(1).Borders.Weight = xlThin            

       .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & AsAddress & ");" & AsAddress & ">=" & Ul1As & ";" & AsAddress & "<" & Ul2As & ")"
       .FormatConditions(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
       .FormatConditions(2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .FormatConditions(2).Borders.Weight = xlThin            

       .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & AsAddress & ");" & AsAddress & ">=" & Ul2As & ";" & AsAddress & "<" & Ul3As & ")"
       .FormatConditions(3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
       .FormatConditions(3).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .FormatConditions(3).Borders.Weight = xlThin            

       .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & AsAddress & ");" & AsAddress & ">=" & Ul3As & ";" & AsAddress & "<" & Ul4As & ")"
       .FormatConditions(4).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
       .FormatConditions(4).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .FormatConditions(4).Borders.Weight = xlThin            

       .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & AsAddress & ");" & AsAddress & ">=" & Ul4As & ";" & AsAddress & "<" & Ul5As & ")"
       .FormatConditions(5).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
       .FormatConditions(5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .FormatConditions(5).Borders.Weight = xlThin            

       .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & AsAddress & ");" & AsAddress & ">=" & Ul5As & ")"
       .FormatConditions(6).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
       .FormatConditions(6).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .FormatConditions(6).Borders.Weight = xlThin            

       .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=LEFT(" & AsAddress & ";1)=""<"""
       .FormatConditions(7).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
       .FormatConditions(7).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .FormatConditions(7).Borders.Weight = xlThin            

       .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=(" & AsAddress & ") = ""n.d."""
       .FormatConditions(8).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
       .FormatConditions(8).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .FormatConditions(8).Borders.Weight = xlThin            

   End With
   ```

The remaining 26 cases is coded similarly, with all three steps repeated for each case. Only the characters "As" in the example will be changed for each case, so that for cadmium, the range is "RngCd", the address is "CdAddress" and the limit values range from "Ul1Cd" to "Ul5Cd".

Below you can see how it looks for the two first cases.

```
'As
 Set rngHeaderAs = Range("A7").CurrentRegion.Find("As*Arsen", LookAt:=xlPart)
 Set rngAs = Range(rngHeaderAs, rngHeaderAs.End(xlDown))
 AsAddress = rngAs.Address(False, False)

 Dim Ul1As As Double
 Ul1As = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(2, "B").Value
 Dim Ul2As As Double
 Ul2As = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(2, "C").Value
 Dim Ul3As As Double
 Ul3As = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(2, "D").Value
 Dim Ul4As As Double
 Ul4As = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(2, "E").Value
 Dim Ul5As As Double
 Ul5As = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(2, "F").Value


 With ActiveSheet

     With rngAs
         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & AsAddress & ");" & AsAddress & "<" & Ul1As & ")"
         .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
         .FormatConditions(1).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(1).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & AsAddress & ");" & AsAddress & ">=" & Ul1As & ";" & AsAddress & "<" & Ul2As & ")"
         .FormatConditions(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
         .FormatConditions(2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(2).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & AsAddress & ");" & AsAddress & ">=" & Ul2As & ";" & AsAddress & "<" & Ul3As & ")"
         .FormatConditions(3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
         .FormatConditions(3).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(3).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & AsAddress & ");" & AsAddress & ">=" & Ul3As & ";" & AsAddress & "<" & Ul4As & ")"
         .FormatConditions(4).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
         .FormatConditions(4).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(4).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & AsAddress & ");" & AsAddress & ">=" & Ul4As & ";" & AsAddress & "<" & Ul5As & ")"
         .FormatConditions(5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(5).Borders.Weight = xlThin
         .FormatConditions(5).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & AsAddress & ");" & AsAddress & ">=" & Ul5As & ")"
         .FormatConditions(6).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
         .FormatConditions(6).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(6).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=LEFT(" & AsAddress & ";1)=""<"""
         .FormatConditions(7).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
         .FormatConditions(7).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(7).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=(" & AsAddress & ") = ""n.d."""
         .FormatConditions(8).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
         .FormatConditions(8).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(8).Borders.Weight = xlThin
     End With
 End With

'Cd
 Set rngHeaderCd = Range("A7").CurrentRegion.Find("Cd*Kadmium", LookAt:=xlPart)
 Set rngCd = Range(rngHeaderCd, rngHeaderCd.End(xlDown))
 CdAddress = rngCd.Address(False, False)

 Dim Ul1Cd As Double
 Ul1Cd = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(3, "B").Value
 Dim Ul2Cd As Double
 Ul2Cd = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(3, "C").Value
 Dim Ul3Cd As Double
 Ul3Cd = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(3, "D").Value
 Dim Ul4Cd As Double
 Ul4Cd = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(3, "E").Value
 Dim Ul5Cd As Double
 Ul5Cd = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Cells(3, "F").Value

 With ActiveSheet

     With rngCd
         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & CdAddress & ");" & CdAddress & "<" & Ul1Cd & ")"
         .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
         .FormatConditions(1).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(1).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & CdAddress & ");" & CdAddress & ">=" & Ul1Cd & ";" & CdAddress & "<" & Ul2Cd & ")"
         .FormatConditions(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
         .FormatConditions(2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(2).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & CdAddress & ");" & CdAddress & ">=" & Ul2Cd & ";" & CdAddress & "<" & Ul3Cd & ")"
         .FormatConditions(3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
         .FormatConditions(3).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(3).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & CdAddress & ");" & CdAddress & ">=" & Ul3Cd & ";" & CdAddress & "<" & Ul4Cd & ")"
         .FormatConditions(4).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
         .FormatConditions(4).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(4).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & CdAddress & ");" & CdAddress & ">=" & Ul4Cd & ";" & CdAddress & "<" & Ul5Cd & ")"
         .FormatConditions(5).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
         .FormatConditions(5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(5).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & CdAddress & ");" & CdAddress & ">=" & Ul5Cd & ")"
         .FormatConditions(6).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
         .FormatConditions(6).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(6).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=LEFT(" & CdAddress & ";1)=""<"""
         .FormatConditions(7).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
         .FormatConditions(7).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(7).Borders.Weight = xlThin

         .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=(" & CdAddress & ") = ""n.d."""
         .FormatConditions(8).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
         .FormatConditions(8).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .FormatConditions(8).Borders.Weight = xlThin
     End With
 End With
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to how this can be made a little shorter?

Comment: What's the reasoning behind using VBA rather than the [built-in](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) conditional formatting interface?

Comment: In order to automate the process into a one-button operation which does the same thing every time.

Comment: You want formatting conditions that vary based on the value of specific cell(s), correct?

Comment: Yes, and the formatting criteria will be different for each row and column. That is, each row will be evaluated for one set criteria.

Comment: I think you might be going about this the hard way.  Built-in conditional formatting (with the `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` option, and changing between relative & absolute cell references where necessary) is capable of [some pretty cool stuff](http://mashable.com/2014/08/19/microsoft-excel-cool-projects/#bFpE5YaY1GqZ).  (This guy figured out how to _use Excel cells as pixels_ to [display a photo using conditional formatting](http://think-maths.co.uk/spreadsheet)!)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked it out. But my lab reports have a varying number of columns and rows, and the rows are not always in the same relative or absolute position. I honestly don't understand how I can solve this using the built-in interface without a massive amount of work every time.

Comment: I'd say add two columns to each row in which you lookup the limits based on the component. Then you can have one or two CF rules which gets their limits from those new columns.

Comment: I'm also thinking one or two rules would do it.  I've lost count of how many complicated VBA questions I've seen on here with unnecessary code while unaware of what conditional formatting _is capable of_ and basically trying to re-write functionality that's already built-in.  A single [properly created] rule can affect _any_ number of row/columns each based on _different formulas or values_ from the workbook or even elsewhere.  There are some great tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

Using the find function and comparing the pollutant name in the analysis file with the pollutant name in the worksheet containing the limit values, I only had to define the limits and the conditional formatting once. This works like a charm and applies conditional formatting for all pollutants that are defined in column A of the limit values worksheet:

```
Dim FndStr As String
Dim FndRng As Range
Dim Ul1 As Double, Ul2 As Double, Ul3 As Double, Ul4 As Double, Ul5 As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet 'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row 'get the last row with data on Column A


For I = 1 To Lastrow
    FndStr = ws.Range("A" & I).Value

    Set FndVal = Worksheets("Grenseverdier_jord").Columns("A:A").Find(what:=FndStr, Lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not FndVal Is Nothing Then
                Ul1 = FndVal.Offset(0, 1)
                Ul2 = FndVal.Offset(0, 2)
                Ul3 = FndVal.Offset(0, 3)
                Ul4 = FndVal.Offset(0, 4)
                Ul5 = FndVal.Offset(0, 5)

            Set FndRng = Range(Cells(I, 2), Cells(I, Cells(I, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))

            With ActiveSheet
                With FndRng

                    .NumberFormat = "General"

                    'Upper Limit 1
                    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(B" & I & ");B" & I & "<" & Ul1 & ")"
                    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
                    .FormatConditions(1).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .FormatConditions(1).Borders.Weight = xlThin

                    'Upper Limit 2
                    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(B" & I & ");B" & I & ">=" & Ul1 & ";B" & I & "<" & Ul2 & ")"
                    .FormatConditions(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                    .FormatConditions(2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .FormatConditions(2).Borders.Weight = xlThin

                    'Upper Limit 3
                    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(B" & I & ");B" & I & ">=" & Ul2 & ";B" & I & "<" & Ul3 & ")"
                    .FormatConditions(3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    .FormatConditions(3).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .FormatConditions(3).Borders.Weight = xlThin

                    'Upper Limit 4
                    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(B" & I & ");B" & I & ">=" & Ul3 & ";B" & I & "<" & Ul4 & ")"
                    .FormatConditions(4).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
                    .FormatConditions(4).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .FormatConditions(4).Borders.Weight = xlThin

                    'Upper Limit 5
                    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(B" & I & ");B" & I & ">=" & Ul4 & ";B" & I & "<" & Ul5 & ")"
                    .FormatConditions(5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .FormatConditions(5).Borders.Weight = xlThin
                    .FormatConditions(5).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

                    'Over Upper Limit 5
                    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(B" & I & ");B" & I & ">=" & Ul5 & ")"
                    .FormatConditions(6).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
                    .FormatConditions(6).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .FormatConditions(6).Borders.Weight = xlThin

                    'n.d.
                    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=(B" & I & ") = ""n.d."""
                    .FormatConditions(9).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
                    .FormatConditions(9).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .FormatConditions(9).Borders.Weight = xlThin
                End With
            End With
        End If
Next I
```

I hope someone else will also find this approach useful.